# Filter dataset for sliderInput after selectInput in Shiny?

Tags: r, web-applications, shiny

I am dealing with NCAA athletic conference income data. I want the user to first select a conference (e.g. "ACC" or "BigTen"). Then, I want a slider to pop up showing the minimum and maximum incomes for schools in that conference.

My data (in a table called `colleges`) looks like this:

```
conf    school         incomeMillions
ACC     NorthCarolina  105.1
ACC     Duke           110.2
ACC     Clemson        94.1
BigTen  OhioState      150.9
BigTen  Minnesota      67.6
Pac12   California     54.3
Pac12   Oregon         76.5
...
```

Here's my code so far:

```
runApp(list(
  ui <- bootstrapPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(inputId = "conference",
                    label = "Choose a conference",
                    choices = unique(colleges$conf),
                    multiple = FALSE)
      )
    ),
    uiOutput("conference")
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    table <- colleges[conf == input$conf],
    minZ <- round(min(table$incomeMillions), 2),
    maxZ <- round(max(table$incomeMillions), 2),
    output$slider = renderUI({
      mydata = get(input$range)
      sliderInput("slider", h3("Z-score range"), min = minZ, max = maxZ)
    })
  }
))
```

I've gotten stuck. How can I dynamically filter that dataset so the user selects from the minimum and maximum income for a particular conference, and not just the whole dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, which has the advantage that because Shiny is smart, will cache the output of `data()` so that even if you call it many times, is only evaluated once.

```
library(DT)
library(data.table)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "conf",
                  label = "Choose a conference",
                  choices = unique(as.character(colleges$conf)),
                  multiple = FALSE),
      uiOutput("slider")
    ),
    mainPanel(dataTableOutput("display"))
  )
)

server = function(input, output){

  data <- reactive({
    validate(
      need(input$conf, "Please select a conference.")
    )
    colleges[conf == input$conf]
  })

  output$slider = renderUI({
    income <- data()$incomeMillions

    minZ <- round(min(income), 2)
    maxZ <- round(max(income), 2)

    sliderInput("slider", h3("Z-score range"), 
                  min = minZ, max = maxZ, value = minZ)
  })

  output$display <- renderDataTable({
    data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```